# ZF2 translate accepting only inline string not Php variables

Tags: php, zend-framework2, po

I'm facing problem while using translator in ZF2. i.e it accepting only inline string not Php variables.

It is working perfect and showing translator word in .PO file after "Update", when i give inline string to translate

```
    $translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
    $translator->translate("message to translate") ;
```

But i want to translate the string which is saved in PHP variable. It is not showing translator word in .PO file after "Update". See the code bellow.

```
    $translator = $this->getServiceLocator()->get('translator');
    $msg1="message to translate";
    $translator->translate($msg1) ;
```

This code is from one of my controller action.

Please advice

Answer (score 0):

You will need to specify a 'text domain', either a default or when you call the translate method. If that is done then make sure $msg1 actually has a string.

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.i18n.translating.html

> $translator->translate($message, $textDomain, $locale);
>
> The message is the ID of your message to translate. If it does not
>   exist in the loader translations or is empty, the original message ID
>   will be returned. The text domain parameter is the one you specified
>   when adding translations. If omitted, the default text domain will be
>   used. The locale parameter will usually not be used in this context,
>   as by default the locale is taken from the locale set in the
>   translator.

Comment: Thanks @Rijidael. Why we need text domain.what is expected value of $textDomain?